# Can client mock a cookie?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I'm using ASP.NET and create a cookie on server, like this:

```
public void LoginCookie(string id, string name, string loc)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("login");

            cookie["name"] = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(name); // user name
            cookie["avatar"] = loc; // user avatar location
            cookie["accountId"] = id; // user id
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(180); // default expiring

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
```

And here is the code to check if user is login:

```
if (Request.Cookies["login"] != null)
{
   // login successful
}
```

My trouble is: Any client can view the cookie values easily. So, what's happen if he mocks a new cookie with the same name `login` and same values `name, avatar, accountId`?

If he does that, he needn't be login (same meaning with *login without a password*).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: which url will this be? i am sure i wont register on that webapp :)

there is SO much documentary on how to make a login system. are you really going to write that on your own? with cookies? ;_;

Comment: @Alex Yes. I had referenced the document. But all of them tell me `how to create or how to use a cookie`, not tell me `how to protect cookie values` just like my example. I'm new with cookie. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Nope, I would use ready-to-use solutions

Comment: @Alex -- why does this seem hard to you, should be a couple of hours at most using ASP.NET's built in encryption routines.

Comment: Why not use the built in Membership functionality to handle the authorization/authentication?

Comment: @HaukurHaf this question is still just as valid even when user id is not the data you want to store in a cookie that can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to store a hash of the username and the username in the cookie.  Since the client does not know how you generate the hash (and you should generate with a cryptographically strong method) and can't generate one you can verify the user was the one you authenticated by checking the hash.  To be really safe you probably want to include a time stamp in the hash.

Or you could encrypt the username (or more often userid) after authentication and store that.  This is the most common method.

You could also use SSL or TLS and the cookies will be encrypted.  However, this does not stop the client just people spying on the client.

Comment: SSL is expensive for me, hash cookie values is a good solution. Many thanks Mr. Hogan